# Datatype to use in HUE (Hadoop UI) for currency fields containing a "$"

Tags: hadoop, type-conversion, hue, bigdata

I'm trying to upload a .csv that contains a currency column into HUE using the Metastore Tables feature however there doesn't seems to be a currency datatype in HUE and Hue doesn't recognise the $ to the extent that a float will not work.  Strings also won't work because I need to perform aggregations on the currency column.

Here's an example dataset containing a currency column: 
https://data.cms.gov/Medicare-Inpatient/Inpatient-Prospective-Payment-System-IPPS-Provider/97k6-zzx3

Thanks.

Comment: use `string`, remove `$` using `substr`, then `cast ( x as int )` , then `+` and voila.

Comment: I expected currency datatypes to be built into HUE - something similar to MS SQL Server's "money" datatype.  There's nothing that straightforward?

Comment: Nope, I don't think so. @RyanChase